# Teamcity + Docker:selenium/standalone-chrome file download issue

Tags: docker, selenium, teamcity

I am running my selenium test suite in Docker and configured with Teamcity for CI. I have one test case to verify file download which is working fine if I am running from my linux machine and It's getting failed on running through Teamcity.

Below could be the reason which I got from another post but I am not able to solve this.

*When running "docker-compose up" if you don't have the "download" folder created (host machine) it creates the folder with root permissions and with no write permissions preventing chromedriver from downloads files*.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/548#issuecomment-346073488

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    shm_size: 4G
    volumes:
      - ./src/test/resources/Downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads
```

Can anyone please help meout, if I can change the directory permission through teamcity? And if is there any better solution would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing files and directories in TeamCity, I add a build step to the build config before the tests are run. Just use the command line runner type, with something like `chmod +X /home/seluser/Downloads`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked .
I have used:  chmod 777 src/test/resources/Downloads